# For endless loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop

The following for-loop never ends because of the `tv_year+1` if i remove the `+1` it works fine. can't figure out whats wrong with what i'm doing.

```
  counter = tv_year+1
  for (var i = fv_year; i < counter; i++) {
  alert(i)
  }
```

Comment: We can make guesses, but it's impossible to know for sure, since you haven't told us what the value of the `fv_year` variable is.

Comment: Make sure your counter is a number. If counter is evaluating as NaN then i < counter will not evaluate as expected.

Comment: Can you explain what your code is doing?

Comment: `tv_year != fv_year` Is this a typo or intentional?

Comment: What are the values of `tv_year` and `fv_year` prior to when this code creates an infinite loop?

Comment: could you please post the value of 'tv_year'  and 'counter'

Comment: Try using the debugging features of your browser, or with Firebug in Firefox. Stepping through your loop and watching the values of the variable should tell you what's going wrong. There's no answer based solely on the snippit you've provided.

Comment: Are you incrementing counter inside the loop but not including it in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo...
Change `fv_year` to `tv_year`

Plus, try

```
var counter = parseInt(tv_year,10)+1;
```

Comment: It is possible that you are adding 1 to a string... That would be why it does not loop forever when you don't do it.